# How to do Pagination with filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to make paginable service with filter but its fail to resultset

Here is my controller

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/PageFilter")
    public DataResponsePagination<HistoryBankWrapper, HistoryBank> pageFilter(
        @RequestParam("filter") String keyfilter ,
        @RequestParam("sortField") String field ,
        @RequestParam("sortOrder") String order ,
        @RequestParam("page") int page, 
        @RequestParam("size") int size) {
        return new DataResponsePagination<HistoryBankWrapper, HistoryBank>(historyBankService.findByFilter(keyfilter,field,order, page, size));
    }
```

Here is my service

```
public PaginationList<HistoryBankWrapper, HistoryBank> findByFilter(String keyfilter,String sortField,String sortOrder, int page, int size) {
    Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    Page<HistoryBank> historyPage = historyBankRepository.findAllFilter(keyfilter, sortField, sortOrder, paging);
    List<HistoryBank> historyList =  historyPage.getContent();
    List<HistoryBankWrapper> historyWrapperList = toWrapperList(historyList);
    return new PaginationList<HistoryBankWrapper, HistoryBank>(historyWrapperList, historyPage);
    }
```

here is my Repository

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM HISTORY_BANK WHERE :sortField LIKE '%' || :keyFilter || '%' ORDER BY :sortField :sortOrder",
          countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM HISTORY_BANK",
          nativeQuery = true)
Page<HistoryBank> findAllFilter(@Param("keyFilter") String keyfilter,  @Param("sortOrder") String sortOrder,@Param("sortField") String sortField, @Param("paging") Pageable paging);
```

Comment: Use the framework don't work around it. I would strongly suggest to put this in a `Specification` and use the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` to invoke the `findAll(Specification, PageRequest)` method instead of trying to invent your own.

Comment: You can use two ways to create a dynamic filter with pagination, `ExampleMatcher` or `specification` both support JPA

Answer (score 2):

Ditch your own method and use the framework. Use [specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) to create a dynamic query.

Your repository should extend the [`JpaSpecificationExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html) and then you should invoke the `findAll(Specification, Pageable)` from your service. Your service should prepare the `Specification` it needs to build the query.

```java
public interface YourRepository extends JpaRepository<HistoryBank, Long>,
JpaSpecificationExecutor<HistoryBank> {}
```

Your service can then use the aforementioned `findAll` method.

```java
public PaginationList<HistoryBankWrapper, HistoryBank> findByFilter(String keyfilter,String sortField,String sortOrder, int page, int size) {
    Sort sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.fromString(sortOrder), sortField); 
    Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    Specification<HistoryBank> spec = (r, c, b) -> b.like(r.get(sortField), "%" + keyFilter + "%"));
    Page<HistoryBank> historyPage = historyBankRepository.findAllFilter(spec, paging);
    List<HistoryBank> historyList =  historyPage.getContent();
    List<HistoryBankWrapper> historyWrapperList = toWrapperList(historyList);
    return new PaginationList<HistoryBankWrapper, HistoryBank>(historyWrapperList, historyPage);
    }
```

You can even make this easier by modifying your controller to directly bind to a `Pageable` object, that saves you creating it.

```java
public DataResponsePagination<HistoryBankWrapper, HistoryBank> pageFilter(
        @RequestParam("filter") String keyfilter ,
        Pageable page) {
        {
```

Now you only need to create the `Specification` and can just pass along the `Pageable`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Jpa repository you use the symbol of OR (||) try with a keyword or
and modified your query for filtering you have to use and instead of or